# How to get user's web browser using php

Tags: php, browser

I want to get users's web browser name so I can insert it into a database when that user sign's up. This is the code I use to figure out what the site is:

The problem I have is that I don't know what these numbers mean 99.0.1150.55 and 99.0.4844.84. I figured out using `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`that they are some id numbers for Chrome and Edge but I can't find other numbers for other types of browsers.

I also tried using this https://github.com/Fortune-dot/user_info.git however it doesn't work and displays only Chrome regardlles of the browser I am using

````
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '99.0.1150.55') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'You are using  Edge.<br />';
}elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '99.0.4844.84') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'You are using Chrome.<br />';
}elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'You are using Chrome.<br />';
}```
````

Comment: Those seem to be version numbers. What does `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` output?

Comment: It is not worth the trouble to parse out every possible user agent, especially with [plans](https://chromestatus.com/feature/57045537458749440) to make significant changes in this area. I would just store the full UA (if you actually have a reason to do so), and then maybe try to cull more information where you actually use this.